# What are hidden facts of Complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to know how complex number can be used in real life. What are hidden usage of complex number in real life.
Can anyone explain ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space setting for special relativity theory can be considered a regular Euclidean space if the 4th dimension, time, is denoted in imaginary numbers. Is that real life enough?